# lapply(x, quantile, probs = 1:3/4)

Tags: r

I know this is kiddy question, but can anyone explain what happen in probs = 1:3/4 . Its mean take range from 1st to 3rd number, what about '/4' there?

```
x <- list(a = 1:10, beta = exp(-3:3), logic = c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE))
$a
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$beta
[1]  0.04978707  0.13533528  0.36787944  1.00000000  2.71828183  7.38905610
[7] 20.08553692

$logic
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

lapply(x,quantile,probs = 1:3/4) #area of concern
$a
 25%  50%  75% 
 3.25 5.50 7.75 

$beta
  25%       50%       75% 
  0.2516074 1.0000000 5.0536690 

$logic
 25% 50% 75% 
 0.0 0.5 1.0
```

Comment: If you print it out in a console you get `0.25 0.50 0.75`, was that the question?

Comment: If you are asking what is happening then R interpretes this as `(1:3)/4`.

Comment: Thank you.. yes. I want to know how interpret it..

Comment: `1:3/4 -> seq(1,3)/4 -> c(1,2,3)/4 -> c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)`

Answer (score 0):

R interprets `1:3/4` as `c(1,2,3)/4` which is 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 - the percentage shares fed into `quantile` function inside `lapply`.